# Why do I have to reboot my pc twice before I see the login screen?

Tags: boot, grub2

I've been a Windows user for 22 years, but about 6 weeks ago I moved away from Windows and now only run Linux Ubuntu 14.04 on my pc.

The issue I have is that every time I start my computer and it gets to the option display to choose if I want to log onto Ubuntu, memtest, etc.,
the screen only shows the burgundy coloured background then puts my monitor to sleep.

I then restart my pc and voila, the 2nd time I get to the options login screen to choose Ubuntu, etc. This happens every single time and is now really getting annoying. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you press and hold `SHIFT` while booting and post what happens? It should bring up a menu where you can select various options. If it does, try selecting the recovery option (should be there) and seeing if your PC boots correctly.

Comment: Hi terdon, I followed your advise and the 1st time I was able to see the full logon menu. I selected ubuntu, the screen turned black (me thinking, yes, it seems like it is working), but then my monitor went to sleep. I rebooted and was then able to select ubuntu on the menu and could log in. Thanks for your willingness to help though, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you press and hold `SHIFT` from the moment you pressed the power button? If so, did a text-based menu come up? Again, if so, what were the options?

Comment: Yes I did. The options were (if I remember correctly) ubuntu, memtest (and I believe there were 2 options), and the last was Advanced options for ubuntu. Something in that line. I have tested that before when I selected the advanced options and it gave me the options to logon to ubuntu with previous "versions"...if that is the correct word. I will try your advise again later this afternoon when we get back home. The wife and I are heading out. Thanks.

Comment: Try the advanced options with a previous kernel version and see if it works any better (if that option is available.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this has actually been happening from day 1 when I installed ubuntu. I'll be back online in about 3 or 4 hours, so please forgive me if I don't reply soon. Heading out to enjoy a little bit of sunshine! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to thank those who tried to assist me nearly 3 years ago where I had to reboot my pc twice before I could get to the login screen.
In short, the issue was still happening, and I finally decided to accept it and live with it, and only because that from the moment I powered on my pc, it took around 15 seconds until I was able to see the desktop, so it was not really an inconvenience.

About 3 months ago I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS...and since then I have no more issues with having to reboot my pc twice. So issue resolved.
Thanks again all. :)

Comment: This happens to me in Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0` in the `/etc/default/grub` file, then run `sudo update-grub` to update the changes to the grub loader.  Maybe not having a timeout set will help your system just boot right up.  Then if you need to get into the recovery mode later on, you hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during the boot process to bring the menu up.

If you copy and paste the following to a terminal window, it should update the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0` for you:

```
to=`grep GRUB_TIMEOUT /etc/default/grub | awk -F= '{print $2}'`; sudo perl -pi -e "s/GRUB_TIMEOUT=${to}/GRUB_TIMEOUT=0/" /etc/default/grub; sudo update-grub
```

To add the timeout back, copy the following to a terminal window:

```
to=`grep GRUB_TIMEOUT /etc/default/grub | awk -F= '{print $2}'`; sudo perl -pi -e "s/GRUB_TIMEOUT=${to}/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/" /etc/default/grub; sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, have copied into the Terminal. Going to reboot my pc and see what happens. Will provide feedback.

Comment: Thanks Terrance, appreciate your willingness to help. However, it did not work. I'm not sure if it could be some hardware issue with my desktop pc, as when I was using Win 8.1 Pro, my pc kept on freezing. That's why I decided to go with Linux hoping that it would fix it. Linux has been running fantastic, no issues, only the fact that I have to boot my pc twice before I can logon. I can live with that, just very happy that my pc is not freezing anymore! Thanks again. :0)

Comment: @viskop-kapenaar No problem for the help.  I wish I was more help for you.  Maybe you should look into running the Memtest on your system and see if possible bad RAM.  You can also look into Hiren's Boot CD that is full of diagnostics utilities that you can run on your system to see if there are problems.  You can also check your hard drive for bad sectors with with badblocks by typing in `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda`.  Just some other ideas.  Good luck with your system.  I really do hope you can get it fixed soon.  :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the additional ideas, I am running the "badblocks" search now. Will also look into Hiren's Boot CD - I recall hearing about this about 3 years ago, but never had the need for it. Thanks again sir, much appreciated.  :0)